# C# best way to use sql connection in async task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous

net core web api project.
I commonly use logs everywere in my apps to have some additional tracking capabilities for overall system health. Currently, my "logging" happens synchronously, for instance

```
void MyMethod()
{
   Log.Write("initiating");
   //Do Something
   Log.Write("finished");
}
```

Now, Log.Write() will consume time in the main thread as it's, after all, a sql insert.
How can I make Log.Write be, both asynchronous (Task.Run style for which i need no return value, so no awaiting) AND resolve its own sql connection? If Log.Write() uses the same connection my controller/method has, it will be disposed after the main execution and I risk not having an open connection when the async task runs. So Write() must resolve its own connection and it is a method that might be called hundred if not thousands of times a minute.

Thanks!

Comment: Let the connection pooling do its job. Just open a connection from the log method. It does not matter for this purpose that it's async. You have to use a different connection anyway because if you roll back your main connection, your logs will be rolled back too.

Comment: Logging against a Database is not a good idea. Logs are there for cases when stuff goes wrong. Unfortunately there is a lot of things that can and will go wrong with DB connections alone. So the log is not reliable in itself. Making the loggin asychnronously is also not really helping with reliability. Now you have to deal with logging race conditions on top of the normal ones.

Comment: if your logging library is blocking the ui thread, use a different logging library

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Two things I do not get, tho are: This scenario could have been used for something else than loggin. Logging is just a case of sql calls in async methods, that could have been answered. I wonder how a honest question like this gets downvoted, what do you guys think is wrong about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft themselves states that async logging methods should not be necessary since you should not be logging to a slow store:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#no-asynchronous-logger-methods

Comment: I'll mark this as answer for I was not expecting to get a fully detailed answer just a few tips. Thanks